# registry settings for unchecking keep temporary files on my computer for jre

Tags: java

I want to uncheck "keep temporary files on my computer" from Java control panel using either registry setting or java configuration settings on all users machines automatically. Please let me know how to implement this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After putting deployment.cache.enabled=false   on deployment.properties present under C:\Users\\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment , it got unchecked automatically.

Comment: How does that update all user machines?  I've got a network of a couple hundred machines and I need to disable the Java cache on all of them.